# Craft + FeedMe update

Tags: plugin-feedme, updating

I'm trying to update Craft to 4.5.10 which requires **PHP 8.0.2+** but I have Feed Me plugin installed, which is using Cakephp 3.10.5, which requires **PHP >=5.6.0,<8.0.0**.

Is it possible to update Craft to 4.5.10 without removing FeedMe plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are versions of cakephp/utility 3.3 that didn’t strictly require a PHP version. Component will figure that out and pull in the latest compatible version automatically when you run `composer update`.

(There aren’t any known PHP 8 conflicts with cakephp/utility which affect Feed Me.)

Comment: I tried it and I got the same response:

Problem 1
    - cakephp/utility 3.10.5 requires php >=5.6.0,<8.0.0 -> your php version (8.2.0; overridden via config.platform, same as actual) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - craftcms/feed-me 5.2.0 requires cakephp/utility ^3.3.12 -> satisfiable by cakephp/utility[3.10.5].
    - craftcms/feed-me is locked to version 5.2.0 and an update of this package was not requested.

Comment: I tried to remove the Feed Me plugin and then I was able to update Craft to 4.5.10.

After the Craft upgrade, I was able to install the Feed Me plugin.

Thanks Brandon.